# How to quote values of all fields when reading a csv file using pandas read_csv?

Tags: pandas, csv, delimiter

I would like to quote values of all fields of a csv file when reading it using pandas read_csv.

The reason for quoting all values is because there are delimiter characters present in between most of the values.

I tried to indicate QUOTE_ALL(1) in the quoting parameter of pandas read_csv

```
df_new = pd.read_csv('sunlight_data.csv', engine='python', delimiter = '[:,; |_\t %]', quotechar='"', quoting=1)
```

But the resulting DataFrame still got split at the delimiters present in between the values in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the first 5/10 lines of your file.

It's not even clear that the file you're trying to parse can be delimited properly.

With your values for `quotechar` and `quoting`, the parser is expecting that all fields in `sunlight_data.csv` to be quoted. Is that the case ?

pandas is splitting your fields because you're asking him to by setting `delimiter` to `[:,; |_\t %]`.